# python 'rb' mode read() vs. read(1); type of return value

Tags: python

I've read many related threads here and gone deep into the doc (Python 3.6), but didn't find why this happens (captured from Python shell):

```
with open('default_SysEx.syx', 'rb')
 as f:
    x = f.read(1)

x

b'\xf0'

with open('default_SysEx.syx', 'rb') as f:
    y=f.read()

y[0]

240

type(x)
<class 'bytes'>

type(y[0])
<class 'int'>
```

What interprets the single-read byte? is it the read(), is it the list? sequence/iterable/generator/yield/...?

Comment: Both results are exactly the same type, only the length differs.  Look at `type(y)`, and `type(x[0])` - you'll see that they are the same for both variables.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview): _Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a bytes object b, `b[0]` will be an integer, while `b[0:1]` will be a bytes object of length 1. (This contrasts with text strings, where both indexing and slicing will produce a string of length 1)_

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the type of the objects you are printing. While x and y are both `bytes` objects, you are printing the "whole" one character string `x`, while you are printing a single byte of it with `y[0]`.

You will probably find that `x[0]` similarly evaluates to 240.

In other words, `type('\xf0')` is `bytes`, but `type('\xf0[0])` is `int`.